# Execute multiple goals with parameters in maven

Tags: maven, parameters, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to execute multiple goals in maven

I have my Pom.xml like

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jmeter</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>${mytest}</jMeterTestFile>                       
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                    <propertiesUser>                
                        <hostName>${myhost}</hostName> 
                        <port>${myport}</port> 
                        <protocol>${myprotocol}</protocol>              
                    </propertiesUser>
                </configuration>                        
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>create-graphs</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>create-graph</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>verify</phase>         
            </execution>
        </executions>       
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>runcommand</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>   
        <configuration>
            <executable>mvn</executable>
            <arguments>
                <argument>**com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.4.1:jmeter@jmeter-tests -Dmyhost=hix.qa.com -Dmyport=80 -Dmyprotocol=http -Dmythreads=5 -Dmyloopcount=20 -Dmyrampup=1 -Dmytest=ScreenerAPI.jmx**</argument>
                <argument>de.codecentric:jmeter-graph-maven-plugin:0.1.0:create-graph@create-graphs</argument>        
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>     
</plugins>
```

I have two arguments mentioned in the org.codehaus plugin.

running the below command with argument1 disabled works fine.

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec@runcommand
```

But when I run the command with both are arguments enabled gives me an error

> failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.4.1:jmeter@jmeter-tests -Dmyhost=hix.qa.com -Dmyport=80 -Dmyprotocol=http -Dmythreads=5 -Dmyloopcount=20 -Dmyrampup=1 -Dmytest=ScreenerAPI.jmx

running goal1 and goal2 indivudally with parameters from cmd line works fine.

```
mvn de.codecentric:jmeter-graph-maven-plugin:0.1.0:create-graph@create-graphs 
mvn com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.4.1:jmeter@jmeter-tests "-Dmyhost=hix.qa.com" "-Dmyport=80" "-Dmyprotocol=http" "-Dmythreads=5" "-Dmyloopcount=20" "-Dmyrampup=1" "-Dmytest=ScreenerAPI.jmx"
```

How to pass parameters to one goal from command line while running multiple goals?

Comment: You are using very old versions of the meter-maven-plugin and the meter-graph-maven-plugin.  I would suggest updating to the latest versions which are much more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

You want to execute multiple commands, so you want to have multiple [executions](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_configuring_maven_plugins.html) of the plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- First execution executing jmeter-maven-plugin -->
        <execution>
            <id>runcommand1</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase> <!-- you need to write a phase here --> </phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.4.1:jmeter@jmeter-tests -Dmyhost=hix.qa.com -Dmyport=80 -Dmyprotocol=http -Dmythreads=5 -Dmyloopcount=20 -Dmyrampup=1 -Dmytest=ScreenerAPI.jmx</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- Second execution executing jmeter-graph-maven-plugin -->
        <execution>
            <id>runcommand2</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase> <!-- you need to write a phase here --> </phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>de.codecentric:jmeter-graph-maven-plugin:0.1.0:create-graph@create-graphs</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>mvn</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This configuration does multiple things:

- It configures 2 executions for the 2 commands you want to invoke. They are both configured with the correct `<argument>` attribute.
- It factors out the common configuration of those two inside the global configuration element. In this case, this is simply the executable.

There's an important factor though: those executions need to be bound to a phase if you want to execute both of them in a single build. As as example, if you bind them to `verify` then invoking `mvn verify` will invoke the two executions.

Comment: I have many plugins in a POM.xml which are bound to verify phase.. 
So i would like to bind the executions to execution id rather than binding to verify.
Since at different points I need to run different plugins. 
Using mvn verify runs all the plugins with verify phase right ?

Comment: @MonicaThaneer That's correct. Well you need to bind it to the phase you want (`verify` was just an example). But you need to split it into 2 executions, so 2 differents ids.

Comment: apologies I am a newbie to maven! 
how would I use two different execution ids in one command?

Comment: @MonicaThaneer No that's the thing, you can't. I fear you are going the wrong way because that's not something you should make a habit of doing. The "normal" way is to bind plugin executions to phases and invoke Maven by passing in phases (like `mvn install`). In the end, you want Maven to package an artifact and you will invoke `mvn package` to get it. This, in turn, should invoke all the necessary plugins to make that packaging happen. [Read about the Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).